# List all files in directory in image using the sleuthkit but without using fls

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to list all files in a directory in a E01 image using the Sleuthkit. The only problem is that i can't use the fls command. I have the inode number of the directory being 145 and the directory name which is /Users/Hello/Pictures/test.

The output when using the fls command is:

```
fls -f ntfs -o 2048 Thisimage.E01 145

-/r * 216-128-2:    Hello1.jpg
-/r * 217-128-2:    Bye.jpg
-/r * 218-128-2:    TheFATlady.jpg
-/r * 219-128-2:    Snape.jpg
-/r * 220-128-2:    Amazeing.jpg
-/r * 221-128-2:    Thumbs.db`
```

Now i need to get the same using the Sleuthkit but not fls. I am not allowed to mount the file. I hope someone can help i've been stuck on this assignment for days now.